# What does 'truck' mean in 'truck in magical thinking'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [para 4](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/oct/10/-sp-jennifer-lawrence-emma-watson-feminists-celebrity): Around this time last year, as part of an effort to rebrand feminism – a notion that comes up in far too many discussions, as though there might be a magical combination of words and images that will make gender equality more palatable to the masses – Elle UK invited three British ad agencies to develop campaigns to promote feminist messages. I recognized the motivation behind the campaign but I resented the idea that with a better marketing message, the world might get right with feminism. I don’t **truck** in magical thinking.
>
> [ODO page 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/truck#truck-2): [chiefly North American] 1.2 [no object, with adverbial of direction] [informal] Go or proceed in a casual or leisurely way
>
> [ODO page 2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/truck#truck-2): [with object] [archaic] Barter or exchange.

How do you determine/deduce the right definition? The second seems apter, because the writer mentions 'discussions', 'message', but it's supposedly archaic. Please explain the steps, thought processes; I’d like to try to resolve this myself in the future?

Answer (score 2):

In this example, "truck" means "act as a dealer in", which is close to the ODO's second definition.  You might be able to look up the phrase "[have no truck with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+no+truck+with)".  My impression is that:

- The noun meaning of "truck" is "a wagon for hauling things".  (Nowadays, most "trucks" are automobiles, which are either self-powered, or tractor-trailer rigs.)
- "Truck" therefore has verb meanings of "move in a truck" or "haul things in a truck", with a connotation of having business reasons for doing so.

The ODO's first definition seems related to country songs that say to "keep on truckin'".  In American English, a professional truck driver is called a "trucker", and what he does for a living is called "trucking".  "Keep on truckin'" is an informal usage, but the meaning is neither casual nor leisurely.  Most "long-haul" truckers are paid by the mile and/or by the delivery.  Truckers tend to work long hours moving goods quickly, efficiently, and safely.  In the United States, truckers are subject to detailed safety rules to discourage them from becoming too tired to drive safely.

Answer (score 1):

**Choose a better dictionary.**

While the ODO you are using is accurate, it is not comprehensive. And I don't mean switching to the OED.

There are other online dictionaries that offer more definitions than the ODO does. One I use is [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/truck).

A more thorough one is [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/truck). An advantage of this site is that it compiles definitions from several dictionaries. A slight disadvantage is that it can be a hassle to scroll through all the entries, as they can start to get redundant.

However, your mind was correct to steer toward the second definition you cite. But even in that ODO entry, you could have gone further and noticed the idiom that Jasper gets from another website. The ODO includes that idiom under the heading **Phrases**. This idiom gives you a general idea of what *truck* can also mean: *to have or want no dealings with.*

---

In the selection you cite, *truck* is an intransitive verb. ODO does not even have an entry for this. But you can check entries for that in The Free Dictionary or Collins (see the above links).

One synonymous verb given in both is to *traffic.* If you are not sure exactly what this means, you can look this word up. If you use the ODO, unfortunately it once again fails. It's [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/traffic) is *deal or trade in something illegal.* If you relied on this definition, you might get stuck again, because "magical thinking" and "branding", etc are not illegal.

But if you consult [The Free Dictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/traffic), you can see that as an intransitive verb, *traffic* does not necessarily mean *deal or trade in something **illegal**.* Yes, illegal or illicit is "often" or "especially" associated with *to truck in,* but not necessarily.

Last, I did not encounter the word *archaic* in my search. That is, *to truck/traffic in* is not an archaic form.

This answer is not promoting one company over another, or one dictionary over another (at least I am not officially doing so); but I am pointing out that there are differences among dictionaries out there. I do not work for, or get proceeds from, any dictionary company. :)